# Open recyclerview from the fifth element

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a standard `recyclerview` with 20 elements in a fragment. Now what I want is to open the view from the fifth element. Please note that I don't want to `smoothscrolltoposition`. I want it to be open from the fifth element.

**UPDATE:**

I want it to be opened with this **without scroll**-
[image]

I want a functionality where the user can still scroll up-

[image]

And I have already populated my recyclerview.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to populate list with 5 elements first and then populate rest of them ?

Comment: No I have already populated it with 20 elements. I just want the first displayed element to be the fifth one when I open it without a scroll.

Comment: when you are passing the list to the recylerView then remove the first five element and pass to the recylerview

Comment: @AmitRanjan I want it so that the user may still be able to scroll up to view first four elements as well...

Comment: you have to add the first element of the arraylist to 5th position also.

Comment: I am not sure try this recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(5); or ((LinearLayoutManager)getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(5, 0));

Comment: after you populated list with 20 elements, call recyclerView.scrollToPosition(5);

Comment: you will check the condition in the recylerview if the position is 5th then add first element to 5th position and notify your recylerview adapter

Comment: @TanTran I don't want it to be scrolled. I just want it to be opened with the fifth element.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma it will not scroll, it will open from the fifth element.

Comment: Try this If the recyclerview has to show the 5th element very first time only then do a check if the postion  is less than 5 hide those items in recyclerview adapter using a boolean value and when u scroll up disable that boolean.

Comment: I have updated my question. @AmitRanjan, what about the rest of the first four elements, and I also have a scrollbar. Won't this show a discrepancy to the user(due to scrollbar)

Comment: @Raghavendra won't this be a very memory intensive operation, plus there is a lag also.

Comment: Oops @VaibhavSharma yes if u have huge data it'll be a lag.. Sorry I just thought to solving that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try any of these two methods according to your use case. It won't be a smooth scroll.

If you want to scroll to a specific position but that position is the adapter's position and not the `RecyclerView`'s item position. You can only achieve this through the `LayoutManager`.

```
recylerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(adapterPosition);
```

If it is `RecyclerView`'s item position:

```
recylerView.scrollToPosition(itemPosition);
```

Hope this helps you out.

References: [1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#scrollToPosition(int)) and [2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#scrollToPosition(int)).

NOTE:

Try to call this before `onStart` callback method. Because by that time, activity/fragment is **not** visible to the user and thus scroll won't be visible.
Example - If the `RecylerView` is inside an `Activity`, call it from `onCreate`.

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for the effort. But I don't want a scroll/ smooth scroll. I just want it to be opened to a certain position.

Comment: I think, this would open the list at certain position. from where are you calling this method?

Comment: They will be in the recycler view. The user can scroll up to view them.

Comment: I am calling it like this-
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    calendarRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    CalendarAdapter calendarAdapter = new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), calendarDateBeanList, this, date);
    calendarRecyclerView.setAdapter(calendarAdapter);
    calendarRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionToOpenWith);